# Neo4j Aura: Can a user be defined and set a role such as 'publisher'

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-aura

I have created an instance in Neo4j Aura and using the default user `neo4j` I am able to create a user using

`CREATE USER test SET PLAINTEXT PASSWORD 'test'`

This by default sets the user role to [PUBLIC]

I tried to alter the user role to editor using

`GRANT ROLE editor TO test`

I receive an error
`Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden: Permission has not been granted for ASSIGN ROLE`

Is this a limitation of the Aura (free) and Aura Professional edition?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) is available only in Neo4j Aura Enterprise.

[Source link](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/360055750514-Neo4j-AuraDB-and-Role-Based-Access-Control-RBAC-)

Comment: Thanks @degath. So is there any purpose of creating users in the professional edition. For example, can I use users as login and can they add and view data created by others? Thanks